# How to show images with zRSSFeed

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

I'm trying to use ZSSFeed to show some RSS feeds in a very basic way. In fact, I want to start with exactly what their example does:

http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/example_images.html

The script code for that example is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ticker1').rssfeed('http://feeds.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/highlights/tv/list',{
        snippet: false
    }, function(e) {
        $(e).find('div.rssBody').vTicker({
            showItems: 1
        });
    });
});
```

However, when I put the exact same script (with accompanying divs) on my page, it displays the feeds without the images. I can see that the image links are being passed back in content:encoded, but can't figure out how to get zRSSFeed to display them. Any ideas?

Comment: The exact code from their example works fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/XUThe/  You must have some other issue.

Comment: hmm...I can't refute that. Looks like I have some more testing to do...

Comment: If you are integrating this into your site you may have some CSS that is hiding the images.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. For some reason when I implemented the code in my project, I was setting:

```
snippet: false
```

assuming that the images would come in this format. They do not, only when snippet: true.

Thanks to lucuma for the hint in the right direction.